# Corrupted video drivers causing x to go insane

Tags: video, graphics-card, fedora, xorg, troubleshooting

I think X is borked. It's been working for months, then suddenly:

- There's an extra, immobile mouse cursor stuck on the screen.
- `CTRL + ALT + Fn` doesn't work. The screen stops responding, but I can still type commands "in the dark" and they work. All the while, I keep seeing the screen as it was before pressing the key combo. If I press `CTRL + ALT + F2`, it comes back to normal.
- Firefox dislpays erratic behaviour on certain elements, such as an HTML5 youtube window (browser seems to hang) or the gmail checkboxes (a white square surrounds the mouse cursor. t̶̮̹̫̩̹h̜ḙ̶̰ ̫̠͇̞͙͟s҉qu̗̭̹̼a̡͖̜̪͚͔̫͕r̮̪͇e̴̫̥͕̹̞̰ ͉̙̜ḇ̢͈̻̼̤͎̞a̫̘͓̯c̬͎k̖͝g̢̙̜̰̗̫̩͉r͇͓̪̭̣̠͟o̭͟uṇ͓͈͖d̟̝̻̱̳͝ ̡͚̥͖̙̖̘͇i̳̫̭͚͞s͕͚͇ͅ ͖̫̳̣͘f̤̹̠̮͔͍͝i̲͈̤l̗͘l̨̠e̬̺͚͓d̺̕ ̰͎͙̥͠w͍͈̟̬̹ị̶͚̘̟ţ̫̦h̞̫̭̱̟͙ ̴̺̣̳Z͓̲͖̬̹A̫̼̙̯̮̱̹L͇̯̺͠G͙͈̤̺̟̲O̯̘!͔͎̲̭͚̼ͅ)
- I use two monitors, one DVI and one VGA. The right one suddenly became 1024x768 (the other is 1440x900). xrandr detected the max res as 1024x768. Swapping them solved the issue, but it reappeared. I had to replace both the monitor and cable. Not sure if related.

Restarting has no effect.

It may or may not be related to me running `xrandr rotate`.

I'm running Fedora 22. The display driver is `xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.11-2.fc22.x86_64`. -- it is installed, I *think* it's being used. How do I find out?

The video cards are:

- `01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780C [Radeon 3100]`, and
- `02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2] (rev a1)`

Comment: I hate to recommend the use of proprietary drivers, but try the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: To see what driver is being used, check the X logs: `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: How do I install the nvidia drivers? And how do I revert to nouveau if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue in a very bizarre and unintentional way.

I tried to install the proprietary nvidia drivers by following [this tutorial](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia) and performing `dnf install akmod-nvidia "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"`.

I'm not sure if I installed the wrong drivers, or if it conflicted with nouveau, but it resulted in an error message upon reboot. I had to reboot into safe mode and manually remove the newly-installed packages.

**After that, the bug was gone**.